# macOS Time Machine messes up permissions on external volume

Tags: macos, permissions, time-machine

I have an external storage RAID that I use for all kinds of things and share on my network. I decided to allow time machine to use it as backup location but as soon as it started doing it's thing the permissions on the disk are weird.

The moment time machine runs the disk is no longer accessible, the permissions changed to system read/write only and I have to add read/write permission to everyone just so I can see the content again. I tell it to apply to all folders recursively but that doesn't work either and just loads endlessly and I have to force quit finder.

Some folders have ok permissions, some other have something like this that I can't change:

[image: screenshot]

I tried a `sudo chmod -R` but even that gives me `permission denied` errors

Is it possible to use a external drive as a time machine volume next to other things? If yes, how can I fix these permission problems and make sure they won't happen again?

Answer (score 0):

I found if you give the permissions with out the drive mounted it will change ownership and then i mounted the drives

sudo mount -t hfsplus -o force,rw, /dev/sdc3 /media/davidbackup

and have read and write i have to make the drive permissions 777 but i will encrypt the backups 
this is on a raspberry pi smb share i have just set up after weeks of googling 
i have the hfsprogs set up to use time machine
hope it helps